# How to get Host of other flow in Mule?

Tags: mule

I have 2 APIs:

- API A with endpoint: `http://hostnameA/pathA`
- API B with endpoint: `http://hostnameB/pathB`

API A call API B, that mean: Client send request -> API A -> API B. 
Now I want to get hostname of API A at API B (Note: API B is created by me, API A is create by other, I can not touch API A).

Please let me know how to get hostname of API A?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following MEL expression:

```
#[message.inboundProperties.MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS]
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and does not work :(
Also I tried the examples on these links and does not show the ip:

http://mule.1045714.n5.nabble.com/Obtaining-client-IP-address-in-the-HTTP-transport-td5110002.html
http://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/6087/getting_remote_ip_address_and_remote_ip_url.html

This works for me :

```
<logger message="#[java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

Console :

```
[INFO ] 2015-01-01 10:10:10.10 [shared-http-listener.worker.01] [] LoggerMessageProcessor - 20.30.xyz.abc
```